# What is the correct expression to exactly divide \textheight into n rows?

Tags: tables, lengths, height

I want to create a table *exactly* occupying the whole printed area with no space left. The table consists of 5 rows per page, as follows.

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,xcolor}

\newcounter{counter}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcolumntype\specifier{|%
*2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
    |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    |}
}

\makeatletter

\arrayrulecolor{red}

\def\row[#1]#2{%
& \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} \textcolor{red}{#2}}
\ifodd\value{counter}
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}

\let\oldendlongtable\endlongtable
\def\endlongtable{%
\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi
\oldendlongtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
\row[RAM]{Random Access Memory}
\row[BIOS]{Basic Input Output System}
\row[OMG]{Oh My Ghost}
\row[PS]{Post Script}
\row[BJT]{Bipolar Junction Transistor}
\row[DEK]{Donut E. Knot}
\row[B]{Batman}
\row[MS]{Microsoft}
\row[CPP]{C Plus Plus}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Problem and Question

The output has an unwanted white space above the table. It is probably caused by my wrong expression

```
0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax
```

Shortly speaking, how to fix it? What is the correct expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algorithm of setting `\topskip` is applied twice by package `longtable`. Its output routine takes the material from the current vertical list including `\topskip` in a box and reinserts it to the now empty vertical list triggering the `\topskip` setting again. Usually nothing is inserted in the latter case,
because the height of the re-inserted box is usually `\topskip` (because of the former `\topskip` setting). Thus the contribution of the outer `\topskip` is `0pt` then.

The duplicate `\topskip` setting complicates counteractions.

### Variant a)

```
\begin{document}
\null % = \hbox{}, triggers full \topskip
\vskip-\topskip % remove \topskip
\vskip-\LTpre %
% \LTpre would be dropped at the start of a fresh page, but
% there is already material (empty box)
\begin{longtable}{...}...\end{longtable}
```

And the calculation is done without `\topskip`:

```
0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth\relax
```

Also the table should be large enough, to overcompensate the negative
spaces. Otherwise the outer `\tabskip` could become effective.

### Variant b)

This sets the value of `\topskip` to zero temporarily (then `\topskip` does not matter in the calculation):

```
\begin{document}
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{...}...\end{longtable}
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

The result in both cases:

> [image: Result]